# React Native - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.toggleDrawer')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

In my App project I am trying to create a button that if pushed opens the drawer navigator (look at the **toDrawerButton** component in the code below) . My problem is that when pushing this button I get the following error:

> *TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.toggleDrawer')*

this is because **this.props** is a void object (Object {}) and then **this.props.navigation** is undefined.

How can I solve this issue and get my **this.props** object not anymore void?? Thanks!

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import  Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import {Icon, Button} from 'react-native-elements';


const toDrawerButton = ({
    headerLeft: ({navigation}) =>
            (<Button
            icon = {<Icon name='menu' size={24}
                    color='black'
                    onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}/>}
            />)});

// each choiche in the DrawerNavigator will have a stack hiarerchy, this is why for 
// each of them I define a stackNavigator (even if with just one screen at the moment) ------------------
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const MenuNavigatorScreens = () => (
    <MenuNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Menu">
        <MenuNavigator.Screen name = "Menu" component={Menu} options={toDrawerButton}/>
    </MenuNavigator.Navigator>);

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const HomeNavigatorScreens = () => (
    <HomeNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <HomeNavigator.Screen name = "Home" component={Home} />
    </HomeNavigator.Navigator>);

// DrawerNavigator definition ------------------------------------

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerNavigatorScreens = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <DrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen name = "Home" component={HomeNavigatorScreens}/>
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen name = "Menu" component={MenuNavigatorScreens}/>
    </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>);


class MainNavigator extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        }
    render(){
        return (<DrawerNavigatorScreens/>)
    }
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change toDrawerButton to this:

```js
const toDrawerButton = ({navigation})=>({
    headerLeft: () =>
            (<Button
            icon = {<Icon name='menu' size={24}
                    color='black'
                    onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}/>}
            />)});
})
```